# JavaEE 7 ldap Login method

Tags: java, openldap

I am working in a Form to login users against an OpenLDAP implementation.

I want to do soemthing simple that do not depend on the cointainer so I really dont want to use wildfly realms for example.

I was able to make a form and a method that connects correctly with the OpenLDAP server, but for some reason it allways gives me the error of user authentication. (the System.out.println("User OK, pass NO"))

Any idea of what it could be wrong?

My method:

```
 public static Boolean validateLogin(String userName, String userPassword) {
    Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();

    String LDAP_SERVER = "127.0.0.1";
    String LDAP_SERVER_PORT = "389";
    String LDAP_BASE_DN = "dc=domain,dc=moredata,dc=com";
    String LDAP_BIND_DN ="cn=user,dc=moredata,dc=com";
    String LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD ="mypassword";

    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://" + LDAP_SERVER + ":" + LDAP_SERVER_PORT + "/" + LDAP_BASE_DN);

    // To get rid of the PartialResultException when using Active Directory
    env.put(Context.REFERRAL, "follow");

    // Needed for the Bind (User Authorized to Query the LDAP server) 
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, LDAP_BIND_DN);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD);

    DirContext ctx;
    try {
       ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
    } catch (NamingException e) {
       throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> results = null;

    try {
       SearchControls controls = new SearchControls();
       controls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE); // Search Entire Subtree
       controls.setCountLimit(1);   //Sets the maximum number of entries to be returned as a result of the search
       controls.setTimeLimit(5000); // Sets the time limit of these SearchControls in milliseconds

       String searchString = "(&(objectCategory=users)(sAMAccountName=" + userName + "))";

       results = ctx.search("", searchString, controls);

       if (results.hasMore()) {

           SearchResult result = (SearchResult) results.next();
           Attributes attrs = result.getAttributes();
           Attribute dnAttr = attrs.get("distinguishedName");
           String dn = (String) dnAttr.get();

           // User Exists, Validate the Password

           env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, dn);
           env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, userPassword);

           new InitialDirContext(env); // Exception will be thrown on Invalid case
           //show validation suceed
           System.out.println("Validation suceed");
           return true;
       } 
       else 
           //User exist but password is wrong
           System.out.println("User OK, pass no");
           return false;

    } catch (AuthenticationException e) { // Invalid Login

        //Tiro en consola el error
        System.out.println("autentication error");
        return false;
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) { // The base context was not found.

        return false;
    } catch (SizeLimitExceededException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("LDAP Query Limit Exceeded, adjust the query to bring back less records", e);
    } catch (NamingException e) {
       throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {

       if (results != null) {
          try { results.close(); } catch (Exception e) { /* Do Nothing */ }
       }

       if (ctx != null) {
          try { ctx.close(); } catch (Exception e) { /* Do Nothing */ }
       }
    }
}
```

My form is like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head>


        <title>Login LDAP</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>

        <center>
            <h2>Login</h2>

<h:form  id="Login" style="max-width: 50%; border: solid 1px; margin-bottom: 15px">
            <p:growl />
                <p:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin-top: 15px">

                    <h:outputText value="Nombre" />   
                    <h:inputText id="nombre" value="#{authBean.userName}" required="true"/>
                    <h:outputText value="Password" />   
                    <h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{authBean.userPassword}" required="true"/>
                </p:panelGrid>



            <p:commandButton  ajax="false" process="@all" update="@all"  action="#{authBean.validateLogin(authBean.userName, authBean.userPassword)}" value="Login" />
            <br></br>

                <br></br><br></br>
                <hr></hr>
                <small>Todos los campos son obligatorios</small>
            </h:form>
        </center>


    </h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just a remark; void elements should be written as self-closing tags. So `<br/>` instead of `<br></br>`; `<hr/>` instead of `<hr></hr>` etc. The error handling in some browsers will cause some of these elements to be duplicated otherwise.

Comment: I know that but for some reasons Netbeans sometimes fail to deploy the app if I have not both tags (misterys)

Comment: You should use Container Manager Authentication if it's available. Makes everything much easier, and it already works.

Comment: I know that but I really dont want to be container-dependent, I want to make method that do not rely in the cointainer so I can use it in Tomcat,Wildfly oreven Glasfish if needed. So far I found the problem, Is the "search string" I am working on it because I cant figure out yet whats wrong with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method working

```
private String userName;

    private String userPassword;

    private String mensaje ="";

public void validar(String usuario, String password) {

        try {
//Este metodo funciona para validar el usuario, 
//si el usuario tiene nombre y pass correcto devuelve un OK 
//Si el usuario da error entonces cierra la conexion 


//Generamos el DN        
final String dn = "uid=" + usuario +",ou=users,cn=admin,dc=organizacion,dc=com,dc=uy";

//Solicitamos el bindRequest creando una nueva instancia y de parametros el dn y pass
        final BindRequest bindRequest = new SimpleBindRequest(dn, password);
//Nos conectamos al server
        final LDAPConnection ldapConnection = new LDAPConnection("192.168.1.1", 389);
//Intentamos hacer el bind
        final BindResult bindResult = ldapConnection.bind(bindRequest);
//Obtenemos el resultcode de la funcion anterior (SUCCESS o FAIL)
        final ResultCode resultCode = bindResult.getResultCode();



//Si el resultado es SUCESS entonces metemos el codigo aca
// podemos iniciar una sesion, pasar valores a un session bean, etc
        if (resultCode.equals(ResultCode.SUCCESS)) {

            this.mensaje = "Validacion correcta";
        } else {

            //Damos un error y cerramos la conexion
             this.mensaje = "Validacion incorrecta";

            ldapConnection.close();

        }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            this.mensaje = "Mensaje de error";

        }
```

Source:
http://urupro.com/wp/2015/11/24/validando-usuarios-con-openldap-en-javaee/